# In Python, what does dict.pop(a,b) mean?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class a(object):
    data={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'}
    def pop(self, key, *args):
            return self.data.pop(key, *args)#what is this mean.

b=a()
print b.pop('a',{'b':'bbb'})
print b.data
```

`self.data.pop(key, *args)` ←------ why is there a second argument?

Comment: Or if you're really lazy `help(b.data.pop)` in the REPL.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `pop` method of dicts (like `self.data`, i.e. `{'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'}`, here) takes two arguments -- see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.pop#dict.pop)

The second argument, `default`, is what `pop` returns if the first argument, `key`, is absent.
(If you call `pop` with just one argument, `key`, it raises an exception if that key's absent).

In your example, `print b.pop('a',{'b':'bbb'})`, this is irrelevant because `'a'` *is* a key in `b.data`. But if you repeat that line...:

```
b=a()
print b.pop('a',{'b':'bbb'})
print b.pop('a',{'b':'bbb'})
print b.data
```

you'll see it makes a difference: the first `pop` removes the `'a'` key, so in the second `pop` the `default` argument is actually returned (since `'a'` is now absent from `b.data`).

Comment: Just a small small comment which I think that it is important in some situations where user needs to `pop` an element of `dict` but retain the value of the popped element. So, `dict.pop(key)` removes the `key` together with the associated `value` but also returns the `value` of the `key` that has just been removed. I found it useful...

Comment: @flamenco that is what I expect from `pop()` - common behavior across more languages like JavaScript, PHP, Java, although not all languages do that - e.g. C++ .

Answer (score 29):

So many questions here. I see at least two, maybe three:

- What does pop(a,b) do?/Why are there a second argument?
- What is `*args` being used for?

---

The first question is trivially answered in the [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) reference:

> pop(key[, default])
>
> If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default.
>   If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

---

The second question is covered in the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> If the form “*identifier” is present,
>   it is initialized to a tuple receiving
>   any excess positional parameters,
>   defaulting to the empty tuple. If the
>   form “**identifier” is present, it is
>   initialized to a new dictionary
>   receiving any excess keyword
>   arguments, defaulting to a new empty
>   dictionary.

In other words, the `pop` function takes at least two arguments. The first two get assigned the names `self` and `key`; and the rest are stuffed into a tuple called `args`.

What's happening on the next line when `*args` is passed along in the call to `self.data.pop` is the inverse of this - the tuple `*args` is expanded to of positional parameters which get passed along. This is explained in the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax *expression appears in
>   the function call, expression must
>   evaluate to a sequence. Elements from
>   this sequence are treated as if they
>   were additional positional arguments

In short, `a.pop()` wants to be flexible and accept any number of positional parameters, so that it can pass this unknown number of positional parameters on to `self.data.pop()`.

This gives you flexibility; `data` happens to be a `dict` right now, and so `self.data.pop()` takes either one or two parameters; but if you changed `data` to be a type which took 19 parameters for a call to `self.data.pop()` you wouldn't have to change class `a` at all. You'd still have to change any code that called `a.pop()` to pass the required 19 parameters though.

Comment: +1 for the effort.  I fear that the OP's English is not up to the task of reading your answer.

Comment: I wrote that before I read the OPs profile. I've now read said profile and seen several other of the OPs questions. I've just made another attempt, this time using only code :)

Answer (score 7):

```
def func(*args): 
    pass
```

When you define a function this way, `*args` will be array of arguments passed to the function. This allows your function to work without knowing ahead of time how many arguments are going to be passed to it.

You do this with keyword arguments too, using `**kwargs`:

```
def func2(**kwargs): 
    pass
```

See: [Arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

---

In your case, you've defined a class which is acting like a dictionary. The `dict.pop` method is defined as `pop(key[, default])`.

Your method doesn't use the `default` parameter. But, by defining your method with `*args` and passing `*args` to `dict.pop()`, you are allowing the caller to use the `default` parameter.

In other words, you should be able to use your class's `pop` method like `dict.pop`:

```
my_a = a()
value1 = my_a.pop('key1')       # throw an exception if key1 isn't in the dict
value2 = my_a.pop('key2', None) # return None if key2 isn't in the dict
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> def func(a, *args, **kwargs):
...   print 'a %s, args %s, kwargs %s' % (a, args, kwargs)
... 
>>> func('one', 'two', 'three', four='four', five='five')
a one, args ('two', 'three'), kwargs {'four': 'four', 'five': 'five'}
```

---

```
>>> def anotherfunct(beta, *args):
...   print 'beta %s, args %s' % (beta, args)
... 
>>> def func(a, *args, **kwargs):
...   anotherfunct(a, *args)
... 
>>> func('one', 'two', 'three', four='four', five='five')
beta one, args ('two', 'three')
>>>
```

Comment: I read several questions, as detailed in my other answer. I also read the OPs profile and realised that my other answer is useless. This answer should demonstrate at least part of what *args does, which is what I'm guessing the OPs real confusion is, despite the subject.

Comment: @James, +1 for the extra effort.  I'd reached the same conclusion about the real question.